# Is there a combined model which can generate both POS and NER tags using Stanford's NLP Library

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, part-of-speech

Here is an example of a sample text output: 
*Good/NNP afternoon/NNP Rajat/PERSON Raina/PERSON,/O how/WRB are/VBP you/PRP today/NN ?/O*

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

This command will take in a file of input text, and create an output json with all of the tokens, each having their POS tag and NER tag:

```
java -Xmx6g -cp "*:." -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -file input.txt -outputFormat json
```